# react native with AWS backend - set a scheduler

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

I create react native app, as I am not advanced with backends, decided to go into serverless direction and use AWS to authenticate users and store data. I'm still beginner with AWS however I was able to set authentication with cognito plus I store my data in DynamoDB. Thing is that I have a problem and can't find proper solution so would be glad if someone could kindly explain me (preferably in details) how to solve my issue.

So basically my data has few parameters like title, description and image. I store reference to image in my DynamoDb and image is stored in S3 storage. Thing is I wish to schedule auto delete of records from database after let's say 14 days. I was able to achieve that with adding property expirationDate and then set TTL to delete object if expirationDate is older than 14 days. It does work however it does not remove image from S3 storage. It cause that even thought record from database is gone, image is left behind and it cause a mess.
My question is how could I (in relatively simple way) be able to somehow schedule to remove the record from database AND image from S3?

EDIT: Also forgot to mention that expirationDate might be updated by a user so it would be prolonged by another 14 days .

Would be very grateful for any help as I'm trying to crack this problems since many days already.

```
type MyObject @model @searchable @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  image: String
  expirationDate: AWSTimestamp!
}
```

Comment: As per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html), there might be a delay between the expiry of the object and the date/time when S3 removes it. Have you waited some time to ensure the object is not being deleted later?

Comment: I did wait few days, as far as I understand TTL has only impact on DynamoDb and does not modify anything in S3 service

Comment: Did you add the TTL to the S3 object also?

Comment: I did not find such an option in S3, also I think I should not set it in two separate places, I forgot to mention that expiration date might be updates, sorry I will edit it in my question. So if I set two separate rules in s3 and DynamoDB, they would act independently while S3 should be bounded to status of DynamoDB record

Comment: Ok, there are multiple ways to handle this use case. One way would be to use DynamoDB streams, when an record is expired in DynamoDB use the event stream to trigger a Lambda function to delete the associated object from S3.

Comment: Ok so seems like first I will need to learn how to write lambda functions and then will back to you:) So to summarize, I should use this TTL on DynamoDB, then when record gets expired and deleted I should launch lambda function which gets reference of image name and remove this particular image from the S3 storage?